# Using TCP in Standard ML

Tags: sockets, tcp, sml

I'm trying to write a minimal TCP server in Standard ML and getting some type errors I don't understand. What I've got so far is

```
fun sendHello sock = 
    let val res = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\nHello world!\r\n\r\n"
        val wds = map (fn c => Word8.fromInt (Char.ord c)) (String.explode res)
        val slc = ArraySlice.full (Array.fromList wds)
    in 
       Socket.sendArr (sock, slc)
       Socket.close sock
    end

fun acceptLoop serv =
    let val (s, _) = Socket.accept serv
    in print "Accepted a connection...\n";
       sendHello s;
       acceptLoop serv
    end

fun serve () =
    let val s = INetSock.TCP.socket()
    in Socket.Ctl.setREUSEADDR (s, true);
       Socket.bind(s, INetSock.any 8989);
       Socket.listen(s, 5);
       print "Entering accept loop...\n";
       acceptLoop s
    end
```

The latter two functions work fine (if I comment out the `sendHello` line, they typecheck without complaint, and set up a server that prints `Accepted a connection...` every time a client connects).

From what I understand from the [Socket `struct`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/socket.html#SIG:SOCKET.sendVec:VAL), `sendArr` should take a tuple of socket and a `Word8ArraySlice.slice`, which I'm reasonably sure I'm providing.

```
SMLNJ

- ArraySlice.full (Array.fromList (map (fn c => Word8.fromInt (Char.ord c)) (String.explode "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\nHello world!\r\n\r\n"))) ;;
val it =
  SL
    {base=[|0wx48,0wx54,0wx54,0wx50,0wx2F,0wx31,0wx2E,0wx31,0wx20,0wx32,0wx30,
           0wx30,...|],start=0,stop=49} : Word8.word ArraySlice.slice
-
```

The error I get is

```
- fun sendHello sock = 
    let val res = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\nHello world!\r\n\r\n"
        val wds = map (fn c => Word8.fromInt (Char.ord c)) (String.explode res)
        val slc = ArraySlice.full (Array.fromList wds)
    in 
       Socket.sendArr (sock, slc)
       Socket.close sock
    end ;;
= = = = = = = stdIn:35.8-36.25 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: ('Z,Socket.active Socket.stream) Socket.sock * 
                   ?.Word8ArraySlice.slice
  operand:         ('Z,Socket.active Socket.stream) Socket.sock * 
                   Word8.word ArraySlice.slice
  in expression:
    Socket.sendArr (sock,slc)
-
```

Can anyone educate me regarding what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that an `ArraySlice` of `Word8`s is not the same thing as a `Word8ArraySlice`. In order to get the latter from a string, you need to call `packString` with an appropriate array. I decided to use `Vector`s instead, which meant that I could do `Word8VectorSlice.full (Byte.stringToBytes res)` to get a thing I could then send out via `Socket.sendVec`. The below works fine:

```
fun sendHello sock = 
    let val res = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\nHello world!\r\n\r\n"
        val slc = Word8VectorSlice.full (Byte.stringToBytes res)
    in 
      Socket.sendVec (sock, slc);
      Socket.close sock
    end
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be solved, which is fine. However, reading your question, the error message points to the unbound identifier `wd` you used in the expression `Array.fromList wd`; did you maybe mean to use the parameter `wds`?

Comment: @waldrumpus - Correct; that was an incidental error that I ended up catching separately. Edited from the question.